# Not Receiving Email Notification for "Skip Payment" Option in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit, docusign-sdk

I have integrated DocuSign into my application and enabled all the necessary notification events in my developer account. When a payment is made using DocuSign, I am able to receive email notifications to the recipient. However, when I use the "Skip Payment" option, I do not receive any email notifications to the recipient.

I have double-checked my settings and confirmed that all the required notification events are enabled in my DocuSign developer account. I have also searched online for a solution but haven't found any relevant information.

Could anyone please help me understand why I am not receiving email notifications for the "Skip Payment" option in DocuSign and how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I expect to receive an email notification to the recipient when the "Skip Payment" option is chosen in DocuSign, similar to the notification received when a payment is made using the "Make Payment" option.

Answer (score 0):

You will only see payment information when a signer actually makes a payment. If the signer chooses to skip the payment, the email notification will display a blank box where the payment information would normally go, and will have default language like: "Make refunds or payment adjustments through your payment gateway, [Payment Gateway Name]. For questions about refunds or payment adjustments, refer to documentation provided by [Payment Gateway Name]"

If you are not receiving the email notification with this language, I would suggest contacting DocuSign Support so they can review specific envelope examples